# Inserting row in dataframe with less parameters than number of columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There is a one dataframe with 20 columns. (for time being it is of 20 columns but may vary)
I want to insert row with only 4 column values.
I have tried it, by appending NaNs but I didn't succeed

Here is the dataframe:

`df = pd.DataFrame(data={1:'a',2:'b',3:'c',4:'d',5:'e',6:'f',7:'g',8:'h'}, index=[0])`

I want to add row with 'i','j','k','l' for first four columns and rest NaNs

Here is my code:

```
row_len = df.iloc[0].count()
#print(row_len)

def convert(lst): 
    translation = {91:None, 93:None, 39:None}  
    return str(lst).translate(translation)

def Insert_row_(row_number, df, row_value): 
    # Slice the upper half of the dataframe 
    df1 = df[0:row_number] 
   
    # Store the result of lower half of the dataframe 
    df2 = df[row_number:] 
   
    # Inser the row in the upper half dataframe 
    df1.loc[row_number]=row_value 
   
    # Concat the two dataframes 
    df_result = pd.concat([df1, df2]) 
   
    # Reassign the index labels 
    df_result.index = [*range(df_result.shape[0])] 
   
    # Return the updated dataframe 
    return df_result 

NAs = [np.nan]*(row_len-4)
NAs = convert(NAs)
#print(NAs)
row_value = ["i","j","k","l",NAs ]
print(row_value)
df = Insert_row_(1, df, row_value)
```

---

The statement **row_value = ["i","j","k","l",NAs ]** should return
**["i","j","k","l",nan, nan, nan, nan ]** but instead returns
**['i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'nan, nan, nan, nan']** and thus mismatch occurs for number of columns

Comment: Try the below code, maybe that could help you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
 arr = ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
 df = df.append(pd.Series([arr[i] if i < len(arr) else np.NaN for i in range(df.shape[1])], index = df.columns), ignore_index=True)
```

**You can split the above code like this, for better understanding**

```
  arr = ['i', 'j', 'k', 'l']
  co = [arr[i] if i < len(arr) else np.NaN for i in range(df.shape[1]) ]
  a_series = pd.Series(co, index = df.columns)
  df = df.append(a_series, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I did it by simply adding two lists; **["i","j","k","l"]** and **NAs = [np.nan]*(row_len-4)**

Comment: yah `Nans = [np.NaN] * (row_len - len(arr))`, yes you can. But i am telling that you can do all this one line

Comment: Yes bro absolutely